# How to recover the data missing from internal tables(CMPSCOMAPCLASSES) of OWB

Tags: oracle11g

We are using Oracle Warehouse Builder in our project.Accidentally,some of the internal tables 
data got deleted.The impact is when i open the map in OWB,the canvas in completely blank.I cannot see the tables and transformations applied.However when I right click on the map and execute,it does that perfectly fine.But the code is not visible and neither can I deploy that map.The table whose data deletion caused this was CMPSCOMAPCLASSES.We do not have a regular backup of the databse.Hence cannot recover the data.
Can anybody please help me in getting back the data anyhow.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: How was it deleted? Do you have flashback enabled, and was it deleted within the retention window?

Comment: We got a list of the heavy tables from the DBA.This table was one of them and to release space it was deleted.No unfortunately FLASHBACK is not enables.